# Connotations of ἕτεραι?

Tags: koine-greek

Luke 7:36 has a highly sexualized reworking of the plainer and studiously chaste anointment scene from Mark 14. In Luke's version, the woman is γυνὴ ἥτις ἦν ἐν τῇ πόλει, ἁμαρτωλός, a sinning city woman, which I imagine means a prostitute. Immediately afterward, Luke 8:2-3 describes women as active members of Jesus's movement, who traveled with him. After giving a list of male and female followers, Luke adds:

> καὶ ἕτεραι πολλαί αἵτινες διηκόνουν αὐτοῖς ἐκ τῶν ὑπαρχόντων αὐταῖς.

The English translation I normally use [renders this as](https://ebible.org/web/LUK08.htm)

> and many others who served them from their possessions.

From the English, I would have taken this to mean additional male and female financial patrons. But the Greek ἕτεραι πολλαί is feminine. To me as an English speaker, ἕτεραι immediately evoked [hetairae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hetaira), prostitutes. The University of Chicago's [dictionary](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%E1%BC%95%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%82) only gives an entry for the masculine form, which can mean a clansman, comrade, companion, pupil, or disciple. However, they give a subentry below for the feminine form, which seems to have much more specific meanings (not sure if this is exclusive) of companion or prostitute.

Now obviously Luke doesn't mean to say that Jesus's roving band include anything like sexually available groupies or camp followers, and in fact it's pretty clear from the improbable description in Mark 14:3 that Mark, at least, is bending over backwards to avoid the impression that Jesus *is* sinful as well as *consorting* with sinners.

But given the context, what is the connotation of ἕτεραι here? I would imagine that if there was a concept of a man having a "female companion" traveling around the countryside with him, in that culture, then it would have to be his wife, daughter, or slave. Is the word referring to some socially acceptable female role? Would it be jarring to people at the time, like if I referred to my female doctor as my "doctress?" Is the idea to use the word for "disciple," but stick a feminine plural ending on it, so that it becomes "disciplettes?"

It seems odd that the Greek seems to imply that only women, not men, were his financial supporters.